# Spring: anonymous rest call access denied

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been trying to resolve the following issue, but could not reach the root cause.

Below is the concerned code

Spring Security Config

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <!-- Modified for internal projects. Take care while using in other projects -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/me/dashboard"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="true"
        logout-url="/login" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>
```

UserDetails Service  (irrelevant and secure code is not shared) Do let me know if required, will share dummy data/ implementation

```
public class PortalUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService,PortalService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        PortalUser user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities= null;
        if(user!=null){
            authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRoles());
        }
        else{
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username +"is not a valid user");
        }
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    }

    // Converts com.mkyong.users.model.User user to
    // org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
    private User buildUserForAuthentication(PortalUser user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        // Build user's authorities
        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {

            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(getRoleName(userRole.getRoleId())));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return Result;
    }
...

}.
```

If I hit any POST (rest service) e.g.  `/rest/MyRestService` Spring is throwing access denied exception and is converting the request to `/403` as defined in access-denied-handler.

What could be the possible issue?

Comment: For starters, your     <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" /> is in contradiction with the above 1 intercept-url. In the line I pasted, you are saying, anyone can access any url. Then in the above 1 line you are saying only admin can access /admin/*. Which one is it? Secondly, turn on debug mode logging only for spring-security. Then try to do whatever you are trying and failing, and paste the debug log in main post. It's difficult to help without seeing that log.

Comment: I guess, both are correct. but that is another thing, I am invoking a rest api which is other than /admin

Comment: Both cannot be correct, that's what I meant. How can someone have access to all URLS and simultaneously access to /admin/** restricted. I think you took Quantum entanglement a bit too much on heart, but it doesn't apply here. Secondly, you should add the debug logs as I had mentioned for anyone to help.

Comment: okay, please suggest a better way to implement
 to access /admin  role required is ADMIN
For all other flows, everyone should be able to access. even anonymous

Comment: Add logs. M saying this last time.